# Unity DateTime is null after JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not so confident with Unity and C#.
I have a class called UserConnect and after this line used for overwriting data inside an object

```
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(www.downloadHandler.text, this.userConnected);
```

the property  **datelastconnection** is null, and it works only if i convert the property to string, this is how the DateTime arrives from the server

"datelastconnection":"2021-11-15 08:42:00""

```
namespace DataEntities
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class UserConnect 
    {
        public string sessionid;
        public string username;
        public string img;
        public string role;
        public string firstname;
        public int iduser;
        public System.DateTime datelastconnection;

    }
}
```

Any idea how can i solve this issue ? my goal is to save the property of the model as DateTime and not string

should I replace  this command `JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(www.downloadHandler.text,this.userConnected);`
with a custom mapper?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is orbetter **was** a custom JavaScript flavour-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `System.DateTime` is not serializable. As a simple thumb-rule: If you cannot see it in the Inspector it is also not working with `JsonUltility` since they use the same Unity serializer.

You will need a custom serialization for that part e.g. by implementing [`ISerializationCallbackReceiver`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class UserConnect : ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public string sessionid;
    public string username;
    public string img;
    public string role;
    public string firstname;
    public int iduser;
    public DateTime Datelastconnection;

    // serialized backing field that will actually receive the json string
    [SerializeField] private string datelastconnection;

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        // or whatever format you want to use when serializing to string
        datelastconnection = Datelastconnection.ToString("O");
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        // after deserialization try to parse the date string into the DateTime field
        DateTime.TryParse(datelastconnection, out Datelastconnection);
    }
}
```